# EJB 3.1 Stateful Bean behaves like a Singleton Bean

Tags: ejb-3.1, stateful, stateful-session-bean

I'm trying to program an EJB 3.1 using Stateful Session bean.
I should have understood quite well what an EJB is and the difference between stateful, stateless and singleton.

But my stateful bean has a strange behaviour. It behaves as a singleton!!
What I mean is that calling the servlet below (ShoppingCartServlet) from several clients/browsers/machines..., the same bean is returned and the same value is incremented every time.
The "count" value is shared from the clients as the bean was a singleton.

Please, help me to understand!!

Here the code.

**Servlet code**

```java
@WebServlet(name="ShoppingCartServlet", urlPatterns="/shoppingCart")
public class ShoppingCartServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2789580260930727133L;

    @EJB 
    private ShoppingCart shoppingCart;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        int count = shoppingCart.increaseCount();

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();     
        session.setAttribute("count", count);

        String nextJSP = "/shoppingCart.jsp";
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(nextJSP);       
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

**EJB code**

```java
@Stateful
@LocalBean
public class ShoppingCart {

    private int count;  

    public int increaseCount() {
        count++;
        return count;
    }
}
```

Servlet is packaged in a WAR file, and the EJB in a JAR file. Both are deployed in a unique EAR file.

**Edit:** I tried to change my servlet code like below, but now a new Stateful Bean is created on every calls.

```java
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    Context ctx = new InitialContext();         
    ShoppingCart  shoppingCart = (ShoppingCart) ctx.lookup("java:global/jeeapp/jeeapp-business/ShoppingCart!org.madbit.jeeapp.shopping.ejb.ShoppingCart");
    int count = shoppingCart.increaseCount();

    HttpSession session = request.getSession();     
    session.setAttribute("count", count);

    String nextJSP = "/shoppingCart.jsp";
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(nextJSP);       
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could use JAX-RS instead of servlet?

Answer (score 2):

There is single instance of servlet reused for multiple requests concurrently. So, it's the same stateful bean injected, is being shared by all requests.

It's a good practice to have local variables, rather than instance varables for thread safety in servlets. Therefore, instead of injecting at class level, you can lookup bean in method.

---

**Edit :**

You can store the EJB instance obtained through lookup in the `HttpSession` object for future activities. So, the same instance will be reused rather than obtaining it each time & through this way, conversational state will be maintained.

Comment: I would give a stronger recommendation: it is never a good idea to inject a stateful session bean into stateless objects (servlets, stateless session beans, etc.).

Comment: @bkail Thanks for further clarification

Comment: I've changed my code putting a lookup in the doGet() servlet method, but my now now a new Stateful Bean is created on every calls. (See my comment below for more details)

Comment: Maybe it's easier explain you what I would do, that is increment a counter (in the stateful bean) on several jsp pages in the same session.

Comment: @Supertramp Please don't add information as answer, instead update the original post. Also, I have updated answer, refer edit part of it.